# Excel VBA macro: "Object required" in "For Each ... In ..." loop

Tags: vba, excel

This is a VBA macro in Excel 2013.

I'm looping through the cells in Sheet 1, Col B. For each cell, I want take its value and search for that in Sheet 2, Col A. If it's found, I want to take the corresponding value in Sheet 2, Col B and place it in the appropriate row in Sheet 1, Col E.

These sheets:

```
Tagging                 Automatic Categories
B     E                 A     B
hat                     cake  Delicious cake.
cake
arm
```

Should become:

```
Tagging                 Automatic Categories
B     E                 A     B
hat                     cake  Delicious cake.
cake  Delicious cake.
arm
```

Code:

```
Sub AutoCategorize()
Dim c As Range
Dim searchRng As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Tagging").Range("B6:B500").Cells ' loop through cells to do the lookup based on
    If Not c.Value Is Nothing Then ' if there is something in the cell
        If c.Offset(0, 3).Value Is Nothing Then ' make sure the cell to fill is empty
            With Sheets("Automatic Categories").Range("A2:A500") ' using the cells we're looking up in...
                Set searchRng = .Find(What:=c.Value) ' find it
                If Not searchRng Is Nothing Then ' make sure we've found a thing
                    If Not searchRng.Offset(0, 1).Value Is Nothing Then ' make sure it has a corresponding entry
                        Set c.Offset(0, 3).Value = searchRng.Offset(0, 1).Value ' fill it in
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

My problem, I think, is with my understanding of how Excel-VBA structures the data. The MSDN is really unhelpful in this regard, unfortunately, and I've only managed to piece together a lot of how things work from experimentation.

When I run the code, I get

```
Run-time error '424': Object required
```

and the debugger highlights

```
If Not c.Value Is Nothing Then
```

Can anyone shed some light on what's causing the error? I'm pretty sure my logic is okay, but as I say I'm not 100% on how to reference cells/how the data structures work.

I'm new to VB and Excel macros so shout if there's a better way to structure things. This is also my first StackOverflow post so please let me know if I've done anything wrong.

Comment: is the `.Cells` needed in the `For Each c In Sheets("Tagging").Range("B6:B500").Cells` ?

Comment: Formula in E, and code can vanish...   `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Automatic Categories'!A2:B500,2,FALSE),"")` will do what your code is doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error here is that `If Not c.Value Is Nothing` is checking if the value contained in cell c is an *object*, and that that object has not been instantiated.

Since a cell value is a primitive type (really a variant), then the correct check to use is either

`If c.Value <> vbNullString`

or

`If IsEmpty(c)`

your later use of `Is Nothing`, in `If Not searchRng Is Nothing` is correct, as this is checking if a Range object contains `Nothing`.

Comment: I really thinkg `IsEmpty` is the way to go here, but it's worth noting that `IsEmpty(c)` works only because a Range's default property is it's value. What really happens is `IsEmpty(c.Value)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, all sorted now! Also apparently the "Set" in the innermost line (the one that actually fills it in) was unnecessary/inappropriate.

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that before - yes, `Set` is used when assigning object variables, but not primitive types. The equivalent for these is the optional `Let` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`c.value` refers to the value in the cell (text, number, date). This will never be an Object. One way to check the value of a cell (even with only spaces) is

```
If Length(Trim(c.Value)) > 0 Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` of a cell doesn't return an object but a Variant value. Only objects can be tested with `Nothing`. Just write

`If c.Value <> ""`